# Initialise NSString with NSDictionary Object?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How would I init an NSString with a NSDictionary object?
Currently, im using this:
 (string is already declared)
 string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"]];

This works fine as I can NSLog it and everything, however, I cannot pass it to another method for some reason. I have tried doing it with a class named controller like this:
[controller externalEchoString:string]
In controller there is a method named externalEchoString:

```
-(void) externalEchoString:(NSString *) test{
NSLog(@"%@", test);
}
```

For some reason it fails to NSLog the string.... Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: hahaha, yeah I second that..

Comment: I did do it once... I cant for the life of me remember what I did to succeed.... Im very tired so youl have to excuse my ignorance haha

Comment: Look for any of about 100 "how do I pass parameters between classes/view controllers" questions.

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Call the method like this:

```
[ClassName methodName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dicthere objectForKey:@"id"]]];
```

Comment: The stringWithFormat: is unnecessary. I see so many people on this site use that when it's not needed.

Comment: I thought the might be another way. Mind elaborating? Thanks!

Comment: Just eliminate it -- [ClassName methodName:[dicthere objectForKey:@"id"];